# Execute if else statements in Microsoft Word 365 VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-word

I created a form with check boxes and totalled them into variables.

I am trying to give string variables a particular value (e.g., "Pass", "Fail") based on the value of an integer variable exceeding a cut off, e.g., >5 (sums of the check boxes). The values will be set equal to ActiveX labels embedded in the Word document.

I get

> Compile error: End if without block if.

How do I make the else part of the code.

```vb
Sub adhd_diagnosis()

Dim adult_Hyp_Imp As Integer
Dim child_Hyp_Imp As Integer
Dim adult_att_crit As String
Dim adult_hyp_imp_crit As String
Dim child_att_crit As String
Dim child_hyp_imp_crit As Strin
Dim adult_combined As String
Dim child_combined As String
adult_Hyp_Imp = (count_of_2 + count_of_3)
child_Hyp_Imp = (count_of_5 + count_of_6)


If count_of_1 > 5 Then adult_att_crit = "meets"
Else: adult_att_crit = "does not meet"
 
If adult_Hyp_Imp > 5 Then adult_hyp_imp_crit = "meets"
Else: adult_hyp_imp_crit = "does not meet"

If count_of_4 > 5 Then child_att_crit = "met"
Else: child_att_crit = "does not meet"
    
If child_Hyp_Imp > 5 Then child_hyp_imp_crit = "met"
Else: child_hyp_imp_crit = "does not meet"

If count_of_1 > 5 And adult_Hyp_Imp > 5 Then adult_combined = "meets"
Else: adult_combined = "does not meet"

If count_of_4 > 5 And child_Hyp_Imp > 5 Then child_combined = "met"
Else: child_combined = "does not meet"


Label7.Caption = child_att_crit
Label8.Caption = child_hyp_imp_crit
Label9.Caption = child_combined
Label10.Caption = adult_att_crit
Label11.Caption = adult_hyp_imp_crit
Label12.Caption = adult_combined

End Sub
```

Comment: If the action after `Then` is on the same line as the `If` then the `Else` has to be on that same line too. It's better to break it up and put the "Then Action" on the line after the `If`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements - `Else:` just looks line a line label by itself. Maybe you are trying to use the syntax from some other language that has different syntax you are used to?

Comment: See [Using If...Then...Else statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements)

Comment: A matter of taste, but in your case I would use the `IIf`-function: `adult_att_crit = IIf (count_of_1 > 5, "meets",  "does not meet")`

Answer (score 1):

Basically **If ...Then** has **two** possible syntax variations in VBA:

##### One-liner:

**If** *condition* **Then** *statement If = True* **Else** *statement If = False*

##### Block:

```vb
If condition Then  
    'oneOrMoreStatements If = True  
Else  
    'oneOrMoreStatements If = False  
End If
```

In both cases **Else** part is optional. Note that there are no **colons** or anything else. In a one-liner, there is no **End If**, but it is mandatory if you use a block.